# Why am I getting 'getaddrinfo failed' while connecting to remote server?

Tags: python, sockets, getaddrinfo

I am using the `socket` module in python to connect to a remote server at https://vedant-chatroom.glitch.me/chat.html?user=python. This is my code (test.py):

```
import socket
web_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
web_socket.connect(("https://vedant-chatroom.glitch.me/chat.html?user=python", 443))
```

After running I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    web_socket.connect(("https://vedant-chatroom.glitch.me/chat.html?user=python", 443))
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

The remote server is a Node based server which is using the sockets.io package and express.

Comment: The remote address is supposed to be a plain hostname, not a full web URL.  If you just want to do web calls, look into the `requests` module.

Comment: ok thank you i will try